# Hide HTML rows containing only zeros (given a set of visible columns)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table containing just 1's and 0's, except for the first row and first column, which are labels.  The table looks like this:

```
        Apple   Orange   Pear
Farmer1   1       1       1
Farmer2   0       1       1
Farmer3   0       1       0
```

The table is pulled from a huge csv file containing 1's and 0's.  (In the real use-case, there are about 900 rows, and probably up to 20 columns.)  My goal is allow the user to select which columns (i.e., which fruits) to show up, and given the selected (visible) columns, only show those rows that contain at least one "1".

So, if the user wished to hide "Orange", the resulting table show display as follows:

```
        Apple   Pear
Farmer1   1      1
Farmer2   0      1
```

So far---and I'm very inexperienced at web programming---I've integrated the code from [here](http://www.fiendish.demon.co.uk/html/javascript/hidetablecols.html) so that the user can select which columns are visible.  However, I can't figure out how to hide the rows with only 0's in the visible columns.

You can see my partial solution (i.e., just making the columns visible) here:

[**Live Demo**](http://jsbin.com/depehugabe/1/)

---

FYI, I'm not married to the method shown above for hiding the columns.  If it makes more sense to use a different method so as to more easily hide the rows with only 0's in the visible columns, I'm all for it!

---

**UPDATE:** Thanks to @InandaMenezes I have the following further improved solution: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L0ckqyfm/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ffLLe5mw/10/

**Script:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$( ":checkbox" ).click(function() {

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            showColumn(this.name);
            showOrHideRows();
        } else {       
            hideColumn(this.name);
            showOrHideRows();
        }
    });
});    

function hideColumn(columnIndex) {
    $('table td:nth-child('+(columnIndex)+')').hide();
}
function showColumn(columnIndex) {
    $('table td:nth-child('+(columnIndex)+')').show();
}

function showOrHideRows() {
   $("table tr:not(:first-child)").show();
    $("table tr:not(:first-child)").each(function() {
        var validColumns=$("td:visible:not(:first-child)", this).filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == 1;
  }).length;

        $(this).toggle(validColumns!=0);

})

}
```

**HTML:**

```
        <form name="tcol" onsubmit="return false">
        <b>Features:</b>
        <input type="checkbox" name="2"  checked=""/> apple
        <input type="checkbox" name="3"  checked=""/> orange
        <input type="checkbox" name="4"  checked=""/> pear
        </form>

            <table border="1">
        <tbody>
    <tr> <td id="tcol1">Farmer #</td> 
<td id="tcol2">apple</td> 
<td id="tcol3">orange</td> 
<td id="tcol4">pear</td> </tr>
    <tr>
        <td name="tcol1" id="tcol1" class="bold">Farmer1</td>
        <td name="tcol2" id="tcol2">1</td>
        <td name="tcol3" id="tcol3" class="italic">1</td>
        <td name="tcol4" id="tcol4">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td name="tcol1" id="tcol1" class="bold">Farmer2</td>
        <td name="tcol2" id="tcol2">0</td>
        <td name="tcol3" id="tcol3" class="italic">1</td>
        <td name="tcol4" id="tcol4">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td name="tcol1" id="tcol1" class="bold">Farmer3</td>
        <td name="tcol2" id="tcol2">0</td>
        <td name="tcol3" id="tcol3" class="italic">1</td>
        <td name="tcol4" id="tcol4">0</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody></table>
```

Comment: How would your solution need to change if I added the following row (like a header row)? `<tr>
<td name="tcol1" id="tcol1">Farmer #</td>
<td name="tcol2" id="tcol2">apple</td>
<td name="tcol3" id="tcol3">orange</td>
<td name="tcol4" id="tcol4">pear</td>    
</tr>`

Comment: In other words, I forgot to specify that I needed the column names above each column.

Comment: I've changed it to the way you need. By adding :not(:first-child) to the 'table tr' selector it ignores the first row when looking for rows to show/hide

Comment: Could you please change it so that when the page is first loaded, initially none of the checkboxes are checked?  In other words, I would like for the user to start off not seeing any of the "fruit" columns.

Comment: It's just to set checked to false for all of them and hide rows and columns. I've changed it to show you. Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ffLLe5mw/8/

Comment: As part of learning, I am trying to modify your example so that only rows that have all 1's (no 0's) are shown.  (I want to make this new behavior optional in the future.)  So, I added a function `xorRows` that is called after `showOrHideRows`. But it doesn't work.  Could you please help me to see what's wrong with my code in this fidle? [jsfiddle.net/L0ckqyfm/](http://jsfiddle.net/L0ckqyfm/)

Comment: ...basically, I want a separate checkbox that, when checked, makes it so that only rows with **no** 0's are visible.  Whereas, when this separate checkbox is not checked, only rows with at least one 1 are visible (the way it currently works).

Comment: Woops! Wrong fiddle.  Here's the right one: [jsfiddle.net/L0ckqyfm/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/L0ckqyfm/1/). @jfabfab: do you see the problem with my code?

Comment: 1) Do not use val(), use text() for this case. The val() is to get the value of an input element, it's not the case. You want to get the text content of the matched element. 2) Your td selector 'td:not(:first-child)' is wrong because it matches the columns that are not visible, use 'td:visible:not(:first-child)' to match only visible columns

Comment: Sweet!  Thanks so much.  (By the way, please tell me if there is anything that makes my method `xorRows` particular inefficient.)

Comment: No, it's ok. But you do not need to call showOrHideRows before, if you want only rows that have all 1's (no 0's). Currently it does not work if you do not call it before because it' missing $("table tr:not(:first-child)").show(); in the beginning of xorRows. You have to show all rows before choosing which one you want to hide. Otherwise a row that is hidden will never be shown.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69847/discussion-between-synaptik-and-inanda-menezes).

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('input:checkbox').click(function(){
  var checked = $(this).is(':checked'),
      cname = 't'+this.name;
  if(checked){
    $.when($('td[name="'+cname+'"]').fadeIn()).done(restoreRows);
  }
  else{
    $.when($('td[name="'+cname+'"]').fadeOut()).done(hideRows); 
  }
});

function hideRows(){
  $('table tr:visible').each(function(){
    var zeros = i = 0;
    $(this).find('td:visible').not('#tcol1').each(function(){
      i++;
      if($(this).text() == 0)
        zeros++;
    });
    if(zeros && (zeros == i))
      $(this).fadeOut('row');
  });
}
function restoreRows(){
  $('table tr:hidden').each(function(){
    var zeros = i = 0;
    $(this).find('td').not('#tcol1').each(function(){
      if($(this).css('display') != 'none'){
        i++;
        if($(this).text() == 0)
          zeros++;
      }
    });
    if(zeros != i)
      $(this).fadeIn('row');
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="tcol" onsubmit="return false">
  <b>Features:</b><br>
  <input type=checkbox name="col2" checked> apple<br>
  <input type=checkbox name="col3" checked> orange<br>
  <input type=checkbox name="col4" checked> pear<br>
</form>
<p></p>
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td name="tcol1" id="tcol1" class="bold">Farmer1</td>
    <td name="tcol2" id="tcol2">1</td>
    <td name="tcol3" id="tcol3" class="italic">1</td>
    <td name="tcol4" id="tcol4">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td name="tcol1" id="tcol1" class="bold">Farmer2</td>
    <td name="tcol2" id="tcol2">0</td>
    <td name="tcol3" id="tcol3" class="italic">1</td>
    <td name="tcol4" id="tcol4">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td name="tcol1" id="tcol1" class="bold">Farmer3</td>
    <td name="tcol2" id="tcol2">0</td>
    <td name="tcol3" id="tcol3" class="italic">1</td>
    <td name="tcol4" id="tcol4">0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How would I merge your first code snippet with the second code snippet? I'm a little confused on what's going on with the `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` statement.  Could you show me how this solution would be put in JS Bin?  (Sorry, I'm a novice here...)

Comment: The answer involves using a JS library called JQuery (http://jquery.com/) which, in this case, is fetched from google's servers as a demo (but you can get your own copy if you wish) - then the code uses jQuery to do the necessary manipulation

Answer (score 1):

Hi Please check below code it may help you

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmv5uxLn/)

```
Check Above link
```

Comment: Thanks! Is this a different solution from Balaji's above? (Not sure which to "accept" as answer.)

Answer (score 1):

another solution. A slight modification to your current function.
basically, when we'll sum the cell's value on every rows and hide them if the value is 0.

```
function toggleVis(btn){

    var btn   = document.forms['tcol'].elements[btn],
        cells = document.getElementsByName('t'+btn.name),
        nbCols = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0].cells.length,
        i, j, 
        v, val,
        table, row, col;

    mode = btn.checked ? showMode : 'none';

    // Apply the style to the CSS display property for the cells

    for(j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) 
        cells[j].style.display = mode;

    table = document.getElementById("myTable");

    for (i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i += 1) {
        //iterate through rows 
        // we'll sum every cell's value on the row
        //if the sum is null, we'll hide the row

        val = 0;

        // then iterate through columns on this row
        for (j = 1, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) { 
            // we don't want to count the value that are already hidden
            if ( col.style.display === 'none') {
                continue;
            }

            // don't forget the radix on parseInt ;-)
            // we sum the value
            v = parseInt(col.innerHTML, 10);
            if (!isNaN(v)) {
                val += v;
            }
        } 

        if( val === 0) { 
            row.style.display = 'none';
        } else { 
            if (row.style.display === 'none') {
                row.style.display = '';
        }
    }
}
```

here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfabfab/zfpfgcwh/) for you to play with

Comment: This is cool!  Do you think this would be slower or faster than using a pure JQuery solution?

Comment: The pure jQuery should be faster ( Inanda's solution has 2 loops). it should be tested for performance. but for 900 rows it shouldn't make  difference

Comment: Thank you.  I forgot that I needed the column names above the visible columns.  How would your solution need to change to accommodate a first row like this? `<tr>
<td name="tcol1" id="tcol1">Farmer #</td>
<td name="tcol2" id="tcol2">apple</td>
<td name="tcol3" id="tcol3">orange</td>
<td name="tcol4" id="tcol4">pear</td>    
</tr>`

Comment: juste change the start value "i" in the first loop from `i = 0` to `i = 1`. do same for  the top loop `cells[j]`. It's zero-based, which means the first element of an array is 0